# How to set Tab bar selected index to nil or null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I need to set the tab bar selected index to nil because when I launching the my app, the tab bar automatically selected the default index (i.e) 0.

How can I set, the tab bar does not selected any index. if put this,

**[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:nil];**

it gives the **"Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')"** this error.

So Please help me to work on this.

Comment: I think you don't understand the Tabbar. Why do you want to set the index to nil? The selected index is the index of the currently selected ViewController. It's an integer and can thus not be nil. Can you try to describe the problem you want to solve instead of saying what you tried to do?

Comment: Why you need that ?

Comment: A tab bar, by definition, has one of it's tabs selected.

Comment: The default tab bar would be most likely your home view.

Comment: actually in my app i used the tab bar. i know the tab bar is should be selected any one it's tabs but In my app i used left side out bar also. Based upon in my app functionality is if user first time to enter in our app means no tabs are selected from the tab bar controller, they use only the left side out bar not tab bar.  So only i am asking how can i disable the tab bar selection.

Comment: what is this entity "left side out bar not tab bar"? Please show some wireframes.